WPF Application to zoom on screen content
Currently checking on a control that zooms the content on screen of a wpf application.
Struck in calibration part as the zoomed content of the content that is underneath the cursor needs to be shown in this control.
<Border Name="MagBorder" Width="175" Height="100" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1"   >
    <Border.RenderTransform>
        <TranslateTransform x:Name="MagTransform" />
    </Border.RenderTransform>
    <Border.Background>
        <VisualBrush x:Name="MagBrush" Stretch="UniformToFill">
            <VisualBrush.RelativeTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <ScaleTransform ScaleX="10" ScaleY="10" />
                    <TranslateTransform x:Name="MagContentTransform" />
                </TransformGroup>
            </VisualBrush.RelativeTransform>
        </VisualBrush>
    </Border.Background>
</Border>

currently using Mouse Move event to set the TranslateTransform values by taking the current Mouse position and Screen size. Using the below formula to set Translate Transform.
  MagContentTransform.X = (-position.X  + element.Width / 2)/10;
        MagContentTransform.Y =  (-position.Y  + element.Height / 2)/10;

Although this zooms the content, the exact content underneath the cursor is not showing up.
Need help in refining the formula or any other alternative way to do this.

I did something similar using the previous answer Here, Which creates a new Border type that allows for zooming.
You would then implement by doing the following (I included an Image Control)
<local:ZoomBorder
x:Name="ImageZoomBorder"
HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
    <Image
    x:Name="ImageDisplay"
    Margin="0"
    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
    VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
    IsEnabled="True"
    Stretch="Uniform" />
</local:ZoomBorder>

I added some extra Properties for binding bounds to the zooming
    public int ZoomPercentage
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(ZoomPercentageProperty); }
        private set
        {
            SetValue(ZoomPercentageProperty, value);
            CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested();
        }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ZoomPercentageProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ZoomPercentage",
                                                                                                   typeof(int),
                                                                                                   typeof(ZoomBorder),
                                                                                                   new PropertyMetadata(100));
    public int ZoomMinimum
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(ZoomMinimumProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ZoomMinimumProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ZoomMinimumProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ZoomMinimum",
                                                                                                   typeof(int),
                                                                                                   typeof(ZoomBorder),
                                                                                                   new PropertyMetadata(100));
    public int ZoomMaximum
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(ZoomMaximumProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ZoomMaximumProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ZoomMaximumProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ZoomMaximum",
                                                                                                   typeof(int),
                                                                                                   typeof(ZoomBorder),
                                                                                                   new PropertyMetadata(1000));

So i can have a more robust operation on the MouseWheel control
    private void Child_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
    {
        if (child != null)
        {
            ScaleTransform st = GetScaleTransform(child);
            TranslateTransform tt = GetTranslateTransform(child);

            double zoom = e.Delta > 0 ? .2 : -.2;
            if (e.Delta < 0 && (st.ScaleX + zoom < ZoomMinimum / 100.0 || st.ScaleY + zoom < ZoomMinimum / 100.0))
                return;
            if (e.Delta > 0 && (st.ScaleX + zoom > ZoomMaximum / 100.0 || st.ScaleY + zoom > ZoomMaximum / 100.0))
                return;

            Point relative = e.GetPosition(child);
            double absoluteX;
            double absoluteY;

            absoluteX = relative.X * st.ScaleX + tt.X;
            absoluteY = relative.Y * st.ScaleY + tt.Y;

            st.ScaleX += zoom;
            st.ScaleY += zoom;
            st.ScaleX = Math.Round(st.ScaleX, 2);
            st.ScaleY = Math.Round(st.ScaleY, 2);
            ZoomPercentage = (int)(st.ScaleX * 100.0);

            tt.X = absoluteX - relative.X * st.ScaleX;
            tt.Y = absoluteY - relative.Y * st.ScaleY;
            TransformChanged?.Invoke(this, new TransformEventArgs(st, tt));
        }
    }

I also added the event
public event TransformEventHandler TransformChanged;

So some external services could do things based on the transform.

This works for zooming the content, But what i need is in a different way.
I'll be having a control (let's say a rectangle box in the bottom), now when i hover on any part of the screen, That should display the zoomed content in the box.

In the example code that i have given, It's working the way i wanted But have got few issues. Unable to correctly set the Tlanslate Transform position.

if you review the link provided it also incorporates Translation. I think you may need to reword your question, and maybe give some images that explain the result you are looking for (event if its a mock up from Paint). As I am struggling to understand (even with the attempted, clarifying comment) exactly what you are asking for help to accomplish.
